# Как сделать блок популярные песни?

Tags: php, логика

Здравствуйте!

Как на php сделать блок самые популярные песни за "День, Неделя, Месяц"

**Логика хранения песен**.

При загрузке песен в базу записывается (Основные):

1. Название песни
2. Дата загрузки

**Таблица просмотров**

В таблице просмотров 2 столбца:

1. id Песни
2. Количество просмотров

В данный момент я определяю популярную песню с помощью количества просмотров.

**Вопрос**

Как сделать так, чтобы она разделила все по блокам? т.е Разделить на популярные за День, Неделю и Месяц

Помогите пожалуйста построить логику.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей о том как храните песни и как определяете, что одна песня более популярна, чем другая.

Comment: Извините, исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно сформировать запрос на выборку из базы данных. Предположу, что есть таблицы `song (id, name, created)` и `views (song_id, count)`, тогда выборку популярных песен делаем так (пример на `MYSQL`):

```
SELECT * FROM song AS s 
    JOIN views as v ON s.id = v.song_id
WHERE s.created BETWEEN начальная_дата AND конечная_дата
ORDER BY count DESC
```